# How can I add/remove members from an LDAP group with django-ldapdb?

Tags: django, ldap, django-ldapdb

I currently use django-ldapdb to inspect an LDAP database. I can view users, and groups of the form `DN: cn=chat,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com` with a `member` list attribute.

Can I additionally use it to add and remove members from an LDAP group? The documentation doesn't explicitly mention this.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment git page for [django-ldapdb](https://github.com/django-ldapdb/django-ldapdb) contains following example for Group model in LDAP DB:

```
from ldapdb.models.fields import CharField, IntegerField, ListField
import ldapdb.models

class LdapGroup(ldapdb.models.Model):
    """
    Class for representing an LDAP group entry.
    """
    # LDAP meta-data
    base_dn = "ou=groups,dc=nodomain,dc=org"
    object_classes = ['posixGroup']

    # posixGroup attributes
    gid = IntegerField(db_column='gidNumber', unique=True)
    name = CharField(db_column='cn', max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    members = ListField(db_column='memberUid')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Use following example code for adding user in group:

```
user_dn = 'cn=SOME,ou=EXAMPLE,dc=nodomain,dc=org'
group_dn = 'cn=SOME,ou=groups,dc=nodomain,dc=org'
group = LdapGroup.objects.get(dn=group_dn)
group.members.append(user_dn)
group.save()
```

For removing user from group:

```
del group.members[group.members.index(user_dn)]
group.save()
```

Also pay attention on `members = ListField(db_column='memberUid')`. Column name `memberUid` could be different in LDAP implementations/settings.

Comment: i get TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' error when using this approach